# Easiest way to open a text file and read it into an array with Perl

Tags: perl

Adding a standard Perl file open function to each script I have is a bit annoying:

```
sub openfile{
    (my $filename) = @_;
    open FILE,"$filename" or die $!;
    my @lines = <FILE>;
    return @lines;
}
```

and I can create a Perl module to do this, but this is so simple I'm sure there should be one out there already.

I'm trying to find a way to read a text file into an array, and I cant seem to find a Perl module out there that can do this simple task... maybe I'm looking too hard and it already came with the standard 5.10 install.

Optimally I believe it would look something like this:

```
my @lines = Module::File::Read("c:\some\folder\structure\file.txt");
```

Comment: I would highly recommend Text::CSV::Slurp for anyone wanting to work with CSV files.  This module worked much better than the two or three others I tried.  The next best was CSV::Slurp::Simple or something along those lines, though not as robust as Text::CSV::Slurp.

Comment: Use 3 arg form of `open()` http://p3rl.org/open

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You have several options, the classic do method:

```
my @array = do {
    open my $fh, "<", $filename
        or die "could not open $filename: $!";
    <$fh>;
};
```

The [IO::All](http://search.cpan.org/dist/IO-All/lib/IO/All.pod) method:

```
use IO::All;

my @array = io($filename)->slurp;
```

The [File::Slurp](http://search.cpan.org/dist/File-Slurp/lib/File/Slurp.pm) method:

```
use File::Slurp;

my @array = read_file($filename);
```

And probably many more, after all [TIMTOWTDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There_is_more_than_one_way_to_do_it).

Comment: Definately like the File::Slurp method.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Note that File::Slurp predates the Perl IO layers, and therefore won't honor the `PERL_UNICODE`/`perl -C` settings which may be surprising when you're trying to write Perl scripts with proper Unicode support. Path::Tiny might be an alternative with better Unicode support.

Answer (score 16):

that is the famous "slurp mode":

```
  my @lines = <FILEHANDLE> ;
```

you may also see [Perl Slurp Ease](http://www.sysarch.com/Perl/slurp_article.html)

Comment: "slurp mode" is more commonly used to mean reading the whole file into a single scalar, by setting the record separator $/ to undef.

Comment: I've seen both array and scalar context described as slurp mode, but I've seen the array style used more often.

Answer (score 15):

I think this is what you are looking for

[File::Slurp](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/File-Slurp-9999.13/lib/File/Slurp.pm)

Answer (score 7):

Also have a look at [Perl6::Slurp](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Perl6-Slurp/) which implements the Perl6 version of slurp and is recommended in the "Perl Best Practices" book.

Some examples....

```
my @lines         = slurp 'filename';
my @lines_chomped = slurp 'filename', { chomp => 1 };
my @lines_utf8    = slurp 'filename', { utf8  => 1 };
```

Answer (score 6):

You might also want to consider using Tie::File, particularly if you are reading larger files and don't want to read the entire file into memory. It's a core module. Also, please refer to [perlfaq5](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-can-I-read-in-an-entire-file-all-at-once%3f).

Answer (score 4):

You've gotten the general techniques, but I want to put in that Perl sort of discourages you from doing that because it's **very** often the case that you can do the same thing you're doing one-line-at-a-time, which is inherently far more efficient.

Comment: A good point, especially when reading into an array.  Arrays imply sequential processing by lines (or records if $/ is being used) which is often better done one-item-at-a-time.  However, there are cases where it is appropriate to slurp.

Answer (score 2):

For quick and dirty, I rather like the simplicity of mucking with `@ARGV`.

```
# Ysth is right, it doesn't automatically die; I need another line.
use 5.010;
use strict;
my @rows = do { 
    use warnings FATAL => 'inplace'; # oddly enough, this is the one. ??
    @ARGV='/a/file/somewhere';
    <>;
};
say q(Not gettin' here.);
```

<s>If perl* cannot open the file, it automatically dies.</s>

---

* - the executable, so please don't capitalize.

Comment: I didn't know that Perl wasn't an abbreviation!  Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Sorry, the note was not for you but for the notorious Capital-P gang. They'll break into your post and capitalize your P's when you specifically meant the executable. The language gets a capital-P--only. There's no anagram, though.

Comment: I thought the capital-P gang was careful to distinguish.

Comment: No, perl does *not* automatically die - it just warns and continues.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend an object oriented approach that does not requires modules outside the CORE distribution and will work anywhere:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::File;
my $fh = IO::File->new("< $file");

foreach ($fh->getlines) {
    do_something($_);
}
$fh->close
```