# In Perl, how can I read the contents of a file into an array?

Tags: perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Easiest way to open a text file and read it into an array with Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761392/easiest-way-to-open-a-text-file-and-read-it-into-an-array-with-perl)

I'm new to Perl and want for each file push the contents of that file in one separate array, I managed to do so by the following, which uses if statements. But, I want something like $1 for my arrays. Is that possible?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
my @karray;
my @sarray;
my @testarr = (@sarray,@karray);
my $stemplate = "foo.txt";
my $ktemplate = "bar.txt";
sub pushf2a  {
  open(IN, "<$_[0]") || die;
  while (<IN>) {
    if ($_[0] eq $stemplate) {
      push (@sarray,$_);
    } else {
      push (@karray,$_);
    } 
  }
  close(IN) || die  $!;
}
&pushf2a($stemplate,@sarray);
&pushf2a($ktemplate,@karray);
print sort @sarray;
print sort @karray;
```

I want something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
myfoo=(@s,@k)
barf() {
  pushtoarray $1
}
barf @s
barf @k
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are going to slurp a file, use [File::Slurp](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/File%3a%3aSlurp):

```
use File::Slurp;
my @lines = read_file 'filename';
```

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, you can't call an array `$1` in Perl, as that (and all the other scalars with a number as their name) are used by the regex engine and so can get overwritten whenever a regex match is run.

Secondly, you can read a file into an array much more easily than that: just use the diamond operator in list context.

```
open my $file, '<', $filename or die $!;
my @array = <$file>;
close $file;
```

You then get an array of the lines of the file, as split by the current line separator which is by default what you might expect it to be i.e. your platform's newline.

Thirdly, your `pushf2a` sub is rather strange, especially passing in an array and then not using it. You could write a subroutine which takes a filename and returns an array, and thus avoid your issue with the internal if statements:

```
sub f2a {
    open my $file, '<', $_[0] or die $!;
    <$file>;
    # $file closes here as it goes out of scope
}

my @sarray = f2a($stemplate);
my @karray = f2a($ktemplate);
```

Overall I'm unsure exactly what the best solution is as I can't quite make out exactly what you want to do, but maybe this will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

don't understand, what you want like `$1` for arrays, but good practice is this code:

i contain files and their content in HoA - hash of arrays

```
   my $main_file = qq(container.txt);  #contains all names of your files. 
   my $fh;      #filehandler of main file
   open $fh, "<", $main_file or die "something wrong with your main file! check it!\n";
   my %hash;    # this hash for containing all files

   while(<$fh>){
        my $tmp_fh;  # will use it for files in main file
        #$_ contain next name of file you want to push into array
        open $tmp_fh, "<", $_ or next; #next? maybe die, don't bother about it
        $hash{$_}=[<$tmp_fh>]; 
        #close $tmp_fh; #it will close automatically
   }
   close $fh;
```

Comment: Instead of opening and closing the lexical file handle, just declare it inside the loop with `open my $tmp_fh, ...`. It will automatically close when it goes out of scope (at the end of the loop iteration).