# What exactly is happening in this piece of perl code?

Tags: perl

So my question is more about the second line, unless I'm wrong about the first. So what I guess is happening in the first is the content of the file referenced by $filename is going in the variable $in, but in the second line, the contents go in the array @data, is that some sort of split? Idon't really know Perl, just the basics because we have to read and make very small changes at work.

```
open(my $in,  "<", $filename);
my @data = <$in>;
```

Comment: Start by reading `perldoc -f open`, your guesses are miles off.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Easiest way to open a text file and read it into an array with Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761392/easiest-way-to-open-a-text-file-and-read-it-into-an-array-with-perl)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`open(my $in,  "<", $filename);`

This [open](http://p3rl.org/func#open)s a file called `$filename` for reading `<` and associates it with the filehandle `$in`.

`my @data = <$in>;`

The `<$in>` syntax is a shortcut for the [`readline`](http://p3rl.org/readline) function, which in list context reads until end-of-file is reached and returns a list of lines.

The split behaviour is implied by the value of [`$/`](http://p3rl.org/var#$/) or [`IO::Handle->input_record_separator`](http://p3rl.org/IO::Handle), which is the input record separator. By default it is `\n`, hence the line by line behaviour.

Comment: Thanks, great explanation, so this <> is the split syntax and $/ is like a default perl variable, don't know how else to put it, that is \n by default and acts as the regex for <>?

Comment: As @Quentin has suggested, https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html will hopefully explain the meaning of the syntax. I don't know if it uses regex under the hood but that variable is indeed a default and changing it means you can use <> to iterate over multi-line records in a file.

Comment: Thanks, will definitely have to look into it, and really learn Perl, because we only use it sporadically, haven't had much time to do so.

Comment: @albuck97 `<>` in this instance is the `readline` operator; it reads lines from the given filehandle, where a line's end is determined by `$/` (which is a string, not a regex).  Because it is used in a list assignment, it will read all the lines available and return them, and then they are assigned into the array.  Note that the lines will still have their `\n` (or whatever `$/` is).

Comment: Thanks @ysth, I thought <> might be the readline operator, but can't work with guesses at work, and with so much to do and the little use of Perl, didn't have much time to go through the documentation thoroughly. Thanks for all the help, really appreciate it.

Comment: @albuck97 No, `$/` is not a regex, unfortunately. That detracts a lot of its utility, just like not being able to combine a record terminator with a max length, `fgets`-like. `perl` will however interpret some `$/` values specially, you should read the whole thing in `perlvar(1)`.

Comment: @albuck97 btw, the "awk has to be better for something" remark in `perlvar(1)` is dumb -- it should be "gawk/mawk has to be better for something". Standard awk will not treat `RS` (the record separator) as a regular expression, either.

Answer (score 0):

File with name `$filename` is opened.
Content of file will be loaded in array `@data` line by line.

Answer (score 0):

```
open(my $in, "<", $filename);
my @data = <$in>;
```

Maybe it'll help you if you saw the corresponding pseudocode to these lines, which would be:

```
input_file_handle = get_input_file_handle( filename )
data_array = get_lines_of_text_from_file_handle( file_handle )
# Now data_array is an array of lines contained in the file.
```

In the pseudocode, `input_file_handle` is the equivalent of Perl's `$in`, and `data_array` corresponds to Perl's `@data`.

Donat wrote:

> I don't really know Perl, just the basics because we have to read and make very small changes at work.

Ah.  I've noticed that much of Perl's non-stellar reputation comes from many of its users trying to use Perl without first formally learning it.  They think that Perl is just like C, and then get frustrated when they see code they never saw in C.  And instead of sitting down with a good beginning Perl book to learn the basics of Perl, they often prefer to just bash Perl.

Now I'm not saying you're that type of person, but I have seen it happen before.  (For example, someone at my job once expressed an extreme hatred for Perl because he couldn't figure out some basic lines of Perl code.  When I explained the lines to him, he calmed down and said that it made more sense to him, now it had been explained.  Go figure -- he was bashing Perl without ever having learned how to use it.)

When I first tried to use Perl, I thought it would be easy, but I had a difficult time understanding it, despite my years of coding experience.  But instead of bashing Perl, I decided to learn Perl from a beginner's Perl book, and soon fell in love with Perl.

So I suggest you do the same, and start learning Perl.  It's not hard to do with the right book.  In fact, I highly recommend the O'Reilly book "Learning Perl" by Randal L. Schwartz, Brian D. Foy, and Tom Phoenix.  It not only does a good job of teaching you Perl, but it also covers many useful Perl idioms and one-liners, as well as providing an excellent introduction to Regular Expressions.

When programmers start to learn a new language like C, C++, Java, Python, or Ruby, they often will start by formally learning it, whether it be by a class in school, an online tutorial, an online class, a book they bought, or a book they checked out of the library.  (This makes plenty of sense.)  But with Perl (more so than any other language I've encountered) programmers tend to forgo formally learning  it and instead just jump right in, and then become frustrated when they have trouble understanding it.  And this unfairly contributes to Perl's lagging reputation.

(I'm not saying that Perl doesn't have its problems; I'm just saying that people should study Perl before criticizing code they don't understand.)

So if you've ever taken the time to formally learn a programming language, please do the same for Perl.  The "Learning Perl" book I mentioned above is a great place to start.